# Associate multiple unique forms to a unique object in Django

Tags: python, django, url, model-view-controller

I'm trying to build a web application using Django where a user can create a 'Project' and within that 'Project', there are four different forms.

My Question is, how do I associate those forms to a specific 'project' in the sense that the form is linked to that specific 'project'.

**I'm close to doing it** but I'm having issues with the 'create-project.html', 'create-request-1.html' and 'create-request-2.html' pages from rendering due to the 'PK' in the 'projects.html' page URL.

The exact errors I get for navigating to those pages is -

```
NoReverseMatch at /projects/create-project/
Reverse for 'initiate_project' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects\\/project\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

Or

```
NoReverseMatch at /project/create-post-1/
Reverse for 'initiate_project' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects\\/project\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

The path is as follows -

```
'projects.html' -
  'create-project.html' -
  'initiate-project.html' - 
    'create-request-1.html'
    'create-request-2.html'
```

I can navigate and go into each unique 'project' (e.g. project 1, project 2) in 'projects.html' but I can't get into my forms ('create-request-1.html', 'create-request-2.html') inside the 'initiate-project.html' page that's within each 'project' in the 'projects.html' page.

Here's my code so far -

**model.py -**

```
from django.db import models

class create_new_project(models.Model):
    list_display = ('project_name', 'project_manager',
                    'technical_lead', 'test_lead')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Create New Project'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Create New Projects'
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_manager = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    technical_lead = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test_lead = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    environment_choices = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3')
    )
    environment = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=environment_choices, default='ICCS')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from main.models import *

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')


def projects(request):
    CreateNewProject = create_new_project.objects.all()
    args = {'CreateNewProject': CreateNewProject}
    return render(request, 'main/projects.html', args)

def create_project(request):
    return render(request, 'main/create-project.html')


def initiate_project(request, pk):
    InitiateProjectURL = get_object_or_404(create_new_project, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'main/initiate-project.html', {'InitiateProjectURL': InitiateProjectURL})

def create_post_request_1(request):
    return render(request, 'main/create-post-request-1.html')


def create_post_section_2(request):
    return render(request, 'main/create-post-request-2.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('projects/', views.projects, name='projects'),
    path('projects/create-project/', views.create_project, name='create_project'),
    path('projects/project/<int:pk>/',
         views.initiate_project, name='initiate_project'),
    path('project/create-post-request-1/',
         views.create_post_request_1, name='create_post_paid_request_section_1'),
    path('project/create-post-request-2/',
         views.create_post_request_2, name='create_post_request_2'),
]
```

**projects.html**

```
  <div class="row">
    <a href="{% url 'create_project' %}" class="card card-1 bg-red shadow m-2">
      <div class="card-body d-flex h-100">
        <div class="text-center mx-auto justify-content-center align-self-center">
          {% load staticfiles %}
          <img src="{% static 'main/images/plus.svg' %}" alt="Plus Icon" height="60vh">
          <div class="mb-3 pt-4 text-white">Create New Project</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    {% for create_new_project in CreateNewProject %}
    <div class="card card-1 bg-white shadow m-2">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title text-red">{{ create_new_project.project_name }}</h4>
        <div class="card-text pt-2 pb-2">
          <div class="mb-3"><b>Project Manager: </b>{{ create_new_project.project_name }}</div>
          <div class="mb-3"><b>Project Lead: </b>{{ create_new_project.project_manager }}</div>
          <div class="mb-3"><b>Test Lead: </b>{{ create_new_project.test_lead }}</div>
          <div class="mb-3"><b>Environment: </b>{{ create_new_project.environment }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
          <a href="{% url 'initiate_project' pk=create_new_project.pk %}" class="text-red">
            {% load staticfiles %}
            <img src="{% static 'main/images/next.svg' %}" class="text-red" alt="Next Icon" height="25vh"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

**create-post-request-1.html / create-post-request-2.html**

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="{% url 'initiate_project' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-black p-3">Cancel</a>
    </div>
```

To better illustrate what I'm trying to do, See the following image - [Visual description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASovK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the href for the a tag in create-post-request-1.html / create-post-request-2.html should be sth like "{% url 'initiate_project' pk=any_pk_you_choose %}" instead of {% url 'initiate_project' %}

Comment: Ah, Just tried changing it with {{request.META.HTTP_REFERER|escape}} and that fixed it. Many thanks. Can't believe it was that easy.